# Not Login in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I created a database in MySQL:

```
$mysql_host = "mysql4.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a6104027_okdocs";
$mysql_user = "a6104027_ok";
$mysql_password = "*****";
```

I can't log in my PhpMyAdmin.

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'iccnt'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The password is correct. I deleted 10 databases and created new, I had no success. I deleted my domain and created new then I created and deleted 10 others databases, but I had no success. I think that the problem is in the host, but I do not know how to ...    Please help. Thanks

Comment: Are you creating a database on remote server and trying to access a local one?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code you showed is not a create database statement, it appears to be PHP code from some application that includes your database connection information (but not the actual database connection). In that code, you're probably trying to connect as user "a6104027_ok". I say probably because we don't see the actual database connection, so I'm just guessing what that code actually does.

Anyway, the error message you get from MySQL when trying to connect through phpMyAdmin is for user "iccnt".

Presumably you haven't changed your phpMyAdmin configuration, so you're likely still using the default authentication method which displays a login box. Use your a6104027_ok username and password there instead of iccnt. If you did change it to 'config', then the username and password are hard coded in to the configuration file, simply edit `config.inc.php` to change them.

If that fails, just ask your host for what username and password to use. That's what their support folks are there for.